# Impossible to decompose a representation

Tags: representation-theory, gap

While brushing up my knowledge about representations I obtained following problem. I 'll indicate the prompts I enter in GAP but won't give the literal responses returned by GAP in order to save space. I start with two 9x9 matrices $ma$ and $mb$:

```
ma := [ [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1 ],
[ -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 ],
[ -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1 ], [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
[ -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ];;
mb := [ [ 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ], [ -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
[ 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
[ -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
[ 0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ] ];;
```

I construct the matrixgroup $g$ generated by these matrices (which is isomorphic to the alternating group on four elements):

```
g := Group(ma, mb);;
```

and the matrix algebra $a$:

```
a := Algebra(Rationals, [ma, mb]);;
```

which is, if I am not wrong, a representation of dimension 9 of $g$.
If I try to decompose the algebra $a$ I obtain no non trivial subrepresentation, as there is but only one central idempotent element: the identity, shown by

```
Size(CentralIdempotentsOfAlgebra(a));
```

But

```
IrreducibleRepresentations(g);;
```

Shows that the highest dimension of an irreducible representation is $3$, so how do I continue to decompose $a$?

Comment: The fact that the *algebra* $a$ has only one central idempotent does not prove that this *representation* has no nontrivial subrepresentation. What you will be able to decompose is not the algebra but this representation.

Comment: Since $ma,mb$ are of order $3$ and trace $0,$ and $mamb,mbma$ are of order $2$ and trace $-3,$ and in view of the [character table of $A_4$](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_alternating_group:A4#Character_table_over_a_splitting_field), I found that this decomposition should be: $3$ times the irreducible representation of degree $3$ (and $0$ times the three representations of degree $1$). But I did not compute the corresponding invariant subspaces.

Comment: @AnneBauval You are right, indeed. The problem is to find subspaces of the underlying vectorspace  $V$ of $End(V)$ and not of $End(V)$ itself.  But I suppose that, for a given change of basis, the matrices of $a$ can be put in the form of "scalar" block matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 
\rho_g(V) & .        & . \\
.         &\rho_g(V) & . \\
.         & .        &\rho_g(V) \\
\end{pmatrix}  $ where $\rho_g(V) $ is the $3$-dim irreducible repesentation you mention.

Comment: @AnneBauval Observe that $g$ acts simultaneously in each of the subspaces, which explains why there is no other idempotent element than the identity.
Another fact to mention is that the characteristic  polynomials of the elements of $a$ are all third powers.

Comment: "Observe that g acts simultaneously in each of the subspaces, which explains why there is no other idempotent" yes, that is what I meant in my first comment.

Comment: "I *suppose* that, for a given change of basis, the matrices of a can be put in the form of "scalar" block matrices of the form [...] where $ρ_g(V)$ is the 3-dim irreducible repesentation ": I indicated in my second comment how to *prove* it, without needing to explicit that change of basis.

Comment: "the characteristic polynomials of the elements of a are all third powers" Amazing! How did you find that for *all*? I found it only for your 2 generators. I even have a proper basis of each but it seems of no use.

Comment: @AnneBauval It was the original question how to find this change of basis using GAP, not to find a proof. The algebra $a$ was already obtained by decomposing , using GAP, the regular representation using eigenvectors of the idempotent elements. The question was how to continue the decomposistion using GAP.

Comment: Your question did not insist on using GAP for the answer and indicated some misunderstandings which my comments tried to clarify.

Comment: Btw, since you now insist on finding not only the decomposition I gave, but an explicit change of basis: what for?

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake was in believing that there is "no non trivial subrepresentation, as there is but only one central idempotent element". You end your post by "how do I *continue* to decompose $a$?" but you did not *begin* to (and rightly so!). What we can decompose is not the *algebra* $a$ but your *representation* $\pi.$

In view of [its character table](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_alternating_group:A4#Character_table_over_a_splitting_field), $A_4$ has exactly four non-equivalent irreducible complex representations, let us call them $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ of degree $1$ and $\rho$ of degree $3,$ hence
$$\pi=a\alpha+b\beta+c\gamma+d\rho,$$
where the non-negative integers $a,b,c,d$ can be determined the following way, which *exempts us from finding explicitely corresponding invariant subspaces.*

- The total degree is
  $$a+b+c+3d=9$$

and (again in view of the character table):

- Since $ma$ (and also $mb$ but one of them is sufficient) is of order $3$ and trace $0,$ we have
  $a+b\mathrm j+c\mathrm j^2=0$
  where $\mathrm j$ is a primitive cube root of unity. Since $a,b,c$ are real numbers, this boils down to
  $$a=b=c.$$
- Since $ma\,mb$ (and also $mb\,ma$ but one of them is sufficient) is of order $2$ and trace $-3,$
  $$a+b+c-d=-3.$$

The solution of this system of $4$ equations on $4$ unknowns is $a=b=c=0,d=3,$ i.e.
$$\pi=3\rho,$$
which means that $\Bbb C^9$ is the direct sum of three invariant $3$-dimensional subspaces $V_i$ ($i=1,2,3$), such that the restriction of $\pi$ to each $V_i$ is equivalent to $\rho.$